# Formatting Marks also show and hides tables

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a weird bug.

The below report is built from from a complex Excel Macro and below is a single page from the report output. The page is built from a range so the report is all in tables which is fine.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-A_d72xVQXtfmVQUFFHdmVvUUdldUpLT1dmRnk4bXowaDNtUWt0eE5yeE1mZHRKNEpyck0&usp=sharing

The problem I am having is that the table Excel has put into this particular page (and about 1-2 others), is that the "show/hide formatting marks" button (e.g. the backwards P at the top of word) also show and hides the table and anything in the table.

I can expand on this as much as needed and have provided a download link as the only way to really show it is for it to be seen by turning the formatting marks on and off. I have removed text on that sheet as some of it is sensitive.

Excel code being used to copy and paste is below. This code works fine for the other 100-200 pages.

```
Sheets(curr_sheet).Range(sp(0), sp(1)).Copy
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste
```

any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're pasting that content into a section of hidden text in Word?  The show/hide formatting button also shows/hides hidden text.

Comment: Ok I've never heard of hidden text in word lol. any idea how I stop it? the document itself is created new when I start the output so would have thought it wouldnt have had any 'odd' formatting etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer thanks to @Tim Williams pointing me in the right direction.

It was because of the hidden text flag being set to true, I do not know how it got set to true as I can not find any reason for it to be.

Anyway if anyone else is looking this sloved my problem

```
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory'select everything
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Hidden = False'Turn hidden off for whole document
```